# Ionic 3: File_URI Not allowed to load local resource IOS

Tags: ios, image, cordova, ionic-framework, camera

Im using the camera to take an image and preview it. It needs to be sent to a server so Im using the destination type of 'FILE_URI'. It works when I run it on android, but Im getting this error running it on ios 10.3.1

Not allowed to load local resource : `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2CE518F3-4F4E-42A9-94E1-DC06D01250C7/tmp/cdv_photo_001.jpg`

I am not running it with the -lc tag. The encoding type is JPEG

Comment: DId you try any of these steps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38795550/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-for-local-image-from-remote-page-in-phonega

Comment: yes I did, but with using Angular/Ionic it gives warnings about how it was unsafe and sanitized the url making it unusable. I tried to bypass it using the DomSanitizer but nothing was working

Comment: Try this: this question will help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53395712/ionic-angular-4-0-0-beta-13-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-with-webview/53414202#53414202

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was facing same problem and I realized that in iOS camera plugin returns source with protocol for new captures but when using it in your HTML to set the source of an element like img or video you need to remove protocol... So I did :

```
if (isIos()) {
  itemSrc = itemSrc.replace(/^file:\/\//, '');
}
```

If you want to move capture to somewhere else restore protocol or make a copy beforehand or whatever

Hope it helps

Comment: This fixes the iOS issue and doesn't cause any issues when applied to Android as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I was running the app in livereload mode and facing the same problem and I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090706/ionic-cordova-fileupload-error-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource), changing from livereload to normal mode solved the problem.

It should help you as helped me, at least for now.

Answer (score 4):

use this `path = normalizeURL(path);` and also read more about [WKWebView](https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/)

Comment: This solution works when you use FILE_URI destination type.

Answer (score 3):

With ionic webview 2.4.1+, you have to use `window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(url);`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54416951/1805493