# Not allowed to load local resource: Ionic3(ios)

Tags: javascript, file, cordova, camera, ionic3

I am getting this issue

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AB6EABD9-CAAF-4AE5-91F9-D8042B34EA87/tmp/cdv_photo_002.jpg

My code looks like

```
let cameraOptions = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }

this.camera.getPicture(cameraOptions).then((imageData) => {
   this.myImage = imageData;
})
```

In android device it works fine but in ios i am not able to avoid this issue i am sure it is due to some security issue it would be great some one help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this might work for you:

```
if (isIos()) {
  itemSrc = itemSrc.replace(/^file:\/\//, '');
}
```

Based off of another thread I saw:

> iOS camera plugin returns source with protocol for new captures but when using it in your HTML to set the source of an element like img or video you need to remove protocol

You can read more about it here: [Ionic 3: File_URI Not allowed to load local resource IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44910984/ionic-3-file-uri-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-ios)

I hope that helps!