# FILE_URI path for Camera not working on IONIC 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

When using the Cameara to take a picture with `destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI`, the resulting URL will not work to display the image. For example, when attempting to take a photo like this:

```
this.camera.getPicture(options).then((url) => {
        // Load Image
        this.imagePath = url;
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Attempting to display it as `<img [src]="imagePath" >` will result in an error (file not found).

The problem here is that the URL is in the `file:///storage...` path instead of the correct one based on localhost.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In previous versions of Ionic, this would be solved by using `normalizeURL`. This will not work on Ionic 4 (or at least I could not make it work).

To solve this issue, you will need to use `convertFileSrc()`:

```
import {WebView} from '@ionic-native/ionic-webview/ngx';
...
this.camera.getPicture(options).then((url) => {
        // Load Image
        this.imagePath = this.webview.convertFileSrc(url);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Now the image URL will be in the appropriate `http://localhost:8080/_file_/storage...` format and will load correctly.

See [WKWebView - Ionic Docs](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/native/ionic-webview/) for more information.

Comment: For displaying the new convertFileSrc url in a template, I still had to use [DomSanitizer](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/unable-to-display-image-using-file-uri/84977/3)

Comment: Amazing!! It's work you saved me as well, two days I was searching :(  Don't get it why Ionic team didn't make a clear documentation on such breaking changes.

Comment: @excbot - I imagine the reason they didn't 'make clear documentation' is because they have to prioritise the masses of work they're giving away to us all for free on this open source project.  I'm sorry to come across as critical I just think it's important we respect the time and effort put in by others for no pay.

Comment: @dr_ermio. It does work. One small issue though, the displaying of the image on the UI doesn't work unless I touch somewhere in the form. Any ideas why it doesn't update right away?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following code works with me

```
const downloadFileURL = 'file:///...';

// Convert a `file://` URL to a URL that is compatible with the local web server in the Web View plugin.
const displayedImg = (<any>window).Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(downloadFileURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case some gots here looking for the answer on ionic4, check this out

["Not allowed to load local resource" for Local image from Remote page in PhoneGap Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38795550/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-for-local-image-from-remote-page-in-phonega)

and look for the answer from @Alok Singh that's how I got it working on ionic4 and even works with livereload

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE december 2021:

You have to install the new [Ionic Webview](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ionic-webview)

RUN:

> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview

> npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/ionic-webview

Import it in app.module and your page where you wanna use it:

```
import { WebView } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/ionic-webview/ngx'; 
image = "";
constructor(private webview: WebView){}
```

Then this will work:

```
this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
 this.image = this.webview.convertFileSrc(imageData)
}, (err) => {
 // Handle error
});
```

And show it in the HTML page:

```
    <img [src]="image" alt="">
```